# Compare tuples of different size and rearrange/Replace tuple elements in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hello I am new to python, looking for way of comparing two of different size tuples say for example tuple `a=(3,4)` and `b=(1,3,4)` compare a and b and rearrange/replace tuple `b` as per tuple `a` (i.e) `b=(3,4,1)` and it should work all different length tuples.

This is sample input list:

```
l=[((1, 2), (1, 2, 4)), ((1, 2, 3), (2, 3)), ((1, 3, 4), (3, 4)), ((2, 3, 4), (2, 4))]
```

This is my code just iterating over list of tuples:

```
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(l):
print a, b
print len(a), len(b)
```

I want output such that when tuple `a` of length `x=2` compared with tuple `b` of length `y=3` should rearrange/Replace tuple b as per positions of elements in tuple a and with all elements of tuple `b` in it. In other words compare tuple of shorter length with tuple of larger length and rerrange/replace the tuple of larger length tuple w.r.t shorter length tuple, with all element of larger tuple in it.

I want Output as:

```
[((1, 2), (1, 2, 4)), (( 2, 3, 1), (2, 3)), (( 3, 4, 1), (3, 4)), ((2, 4, 3), (2, 4))]
```

I have seen concept of sorting in python it sorts the tuples by key parameter but i couldn't find any help for comparing the tuples elements on its position element and rearranging it or replacing the whole tuple.

I would like to have suggestions on it for resolving the issue.

Comment: How do you rearrange? Is it guaranteed that `len(a) < len(b)`?

Comment: Tuples are immutable.  You can't move the elements of a tuple around inside of it, you can only replace the whole thing with a new tuple.  Why don't you come up with a set of rules that takes the two tuples you have, and makes a new tuple to replace one of them

Comment: Hey PatrickHaugh i would like know how we can achieve it (i.e) comparing and replacing the target tuple

Comment: Hey @WillemVanOnsem no tuple length is not guaranteed, i have compare the length as well elements  and rearrage/replace the longest tuple as per the shortest tuple

Comment: @ShafaatHussain Can you guarantee all of the elements of the shortest tuple will be in the longest tuple?

Comment: @ShafaatHussain Also, do you have some code that you've attempted already? If so, could you add it to the question and describe what it's doing wrong?

Comment: @glibdud yes all elements of shorter tuple will be in longest tuple

Comment: @glibdud so far i have not reached any solution, so this the only code i have right now. i am still figuring out how to resolve it.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Thanks for the suggestion of replacing tuple :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out the solution for above problem. Thanks any way all for comments and feed back :)

Input:

```
l=[((1, 2), (1, 2, 4)), ((1, 2, 3), (2, 3)), ((1, 3, 4), (3, 4)), ((2, 3, 4), (2, 4))]
```

Solution Code:

```
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(l):
# print a, b
# print len(a), len(b)
x= tuple(set(a).symmetric_difference(set(b)))
if(len(a)>len(b)):
    new_a=b+x
    l[i] = (new_a,b)
else:
    new_b=a+x
    l[i] = (a, new_b)
```

Output:

```
 [((1, 2), (1, 2, 4)), ((2, 3, 1), (2, 3)), ((3, 4, 1), (3, 4)), ((2, 4, 3), (2, 4))]
```